# Current page url token not using https

Tags: 7, tokens

I have the following token set up: [current-page:url:absolute] in metatag settings.

If I visit my site: https://www.example.com it displays http://www.example.com where I used the token.  Everything else (css,js,etc..) uses https.

Comment: I think this is something that can be reported as a Drupal bug.

Comment: @juankvillegas I actually don't think it's a bug. I had other sites that work with fine using these tokens with https. Can't figure out what is causing it on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a home page rule set up in metatag configuration that had the url hardcoded. Didn't see that at first.